# How do i retrieve ram usage in the form of a percentage using php?

Tags: php, html

As above.

Any help is appreciated, I'm a little stuck on this.

Comment: Describe the issue in the question and show what you've tried. What RAM usage are you trying to see clients, servers? You said `in percentage`, do you already have it in some other form?

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

```
    <?php
function get_memory() {
  foreach(file('/proc/meminfo') as $ri)
    $m[strtok($ri, ':')] = strtok('');
  return 100 - round(($m['MemFree'] + $m['Buffers'] + $m['Cached']) / $m['MemTotal'] * 100);
}
echo "Memory Usage: ".get_memory()."%";
?>
```